# Use typescript to type function argument and return full argument type

Tags: typescript, generics, restrict, narrowing

I have the following function and object as its input:

```
const myResult = myFunc({
  someInnerFunction: (innerArgument) => {
    return innerArgument.myProperty
  }
})
```

And a given type:

```
type MyType = {
  myProperty: number | boolean
}
```

How can i make sure `myFunc` types `innerArgument` as type `MyType` BUT ALSO types `myResult` as the equivalent to the type

```
{
  someInnerFunction(innerArgument: MyType): number | boolean
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, just this:

```
declare function myFunc(p: {
  someInnerFunction: (innerArgument: MyType) => MyType['myProperty'];
}): void;
```

Comment: Yes and No, this will not work for generic arguments. 'someInnerFunction' is arbitrary.

Comment: 'myFunc' should be responsible for typing the argument and the returned result.